# No device screen in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm having problems in Android Studio.  I can't see device screen in activity_main.xml and fragment_main.xml, but as well I see it in content_main.xml. Also, I can't add any elements to screen.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Try the Text button at the bottom. Does it at least exist in there?  Else, are you SURE you are looking at the correct file

Comment: Is something interesting in [studio logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files)?

Comment: Even when I press "Text" button I still can't see render. http://puu.sh/oqCAL/e0d771b854.png

Comment: Log files seems to be okay.

Answer (score 0):

In the preview pane of right side try changing your API level to some lower or higher API it will most probably solve your issue.

[image]